# Return barcode location in the image while decoding with zxing

Tags: c#, kinect, zxing

In my current project, I need to know how to get the location of the barcode in the image with zxing, in pixel or range of pixels. My image source is Kinect v2. The main purpose is to associate barcode with body frame, which requires the location information. I'm using standard Kinect v2 SDK and visual studio 2013, in C#. I feel it's not difficult, but I need some guidance. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me (referencing posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685142/zxing-returns-wrong-position-of-code-39-barcode)) that the ResultFound action should pass a [Result](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Source/lib/Result.cs) including [ResultPoints](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Source/lib/ResultPoint.cs), each with an X and Y value.

It seems like some of the details of those points depend on the type of barcode being parsed, but that would be where I'd start.

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do with the location, you may need to use a CoordinateMapper to get it into the correct coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you! I've been able to get three `ResultPoints` from  `Result` for 2D QR code. I'm now trying to use the CoordinateMapper to locate the points in camera space.

Comment: Although I'm able to get `Result`, it's from a saved image file, which makes the program inefficient. I wish to get `Result` from the `ColorFrame` data stream. But I don't know how to convert `ColorFrame` to `Bitmap` class, which is the argument of `Reader.Decode()` method. Do you have any clue?

Comment: I know this post is kind of old, but have you acheived the binding between bodyFrame and the barcode coordonates ? And do you still have the sources by any chance, I need to do the exact same thing.

Comment: What is the unit of the X and Y? Bananas? Why isn't that in the manual and why aren't it just pixels?

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know how to convert ColorFrame to Bitmap class, which is the argument of Reader.Decode() method. Do you have any clue?

There is a great [Fork of Zwing](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/tree/master/Source/adapters/ZXing.Kinect) that decodes ColorFrame for Kinect V1 and V2.

You simply have to build the DLL and add it to your project.